# Coufused about using cpp to achieve selection sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I tried to implement selection sorting in C++，when i encapsulate the swap function, the output shows a lot of zeros.But at beginning of array codes still work.When I replace swap function with the code in the comment, the output is correct.
I am so confused by this result, who can help me to solve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
int length(T& arr)
{
    return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    a += b;
    b = a - b; 
    a = a - b; 
}


int main()
{
    int array[] = { 2,2,2,2,6,56,9,4,6,7,3,2,1,55,1 };
    
    int N = length(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int min = i; // index of min
        for (int j = i + 1;j < N; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min]) min = j;
        }

        swap(array[i],array[min]);

        // int temp = array[i];
        // array[i] = array[min];
        // array[min] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int showNum = array[i];
        cout << showNum << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: offtopic: [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: `template <typename T> void swap (T &a, T &b) { std::pair<T &, T &>(a, b) = std::make_pair(b, a); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your swap function do not work if `a` and `b` refer to same variable. When for example `swap(array[i], array[i])` is called.

Note in such case, this lines: `b = a - b;` will set `b` to zero since `a` and `b` are same variable.

This happens when by a chance `i` array element is already in place.

offtopic:
Learn to split code into functions. Avoid putting lots of code in single function especially `main`. See [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qn43s7bPc). This is more important the you think.

Answer (score 0):

Your swap function is not doing what it is supposed to do. Just use this instead or fix your current swap.

```
void swap(int& a, int& b){
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
```

Comment: I ran it on my computer with this swap instead and it worked

Comment: it's a common idea when you swap without using a temporary variable,

Comment: my answer explains why and when OP swap fails.